# Cannot Validate SAML sign (Using OpenSAML)

Tags: saml-2.0, sign, opensaml

I use OpenSAML. I get a problem it cannot validate sign

I try to validate after I got I get Response, It' Ok. But when I convert to XML and unmarshall, it cannot validate it.

My Code

```
    Element responseElement = null;
    ResponseMarshaller marshaller = new ResponseMarshaller();
    try {
        responseElement = marshaller.marshall(response); //

        /*
         * SAML utility = new SAML(); Document doc =
         * utility.asDOMDocument(response); // Element target =
         * doc.getDocumentElement();
         */

        Signer.signObjects(signatures);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I use ResponseElement to validate, it works.

MY Code Convert SAMLResponse to String

```
    String samlXmlString = XMLHelper.prettyPrintXML(responseElement);
    BasicParserPool parserPool = new BasicParserPool();
    parserPool.setNamespaceAware(true);

    Document document;
    logger.debug("Parsing...");

    document = parserPool.parse(new StringReader(samlXmlString));
    Element responseElement = document.getDocumentElement();
    logger.debug("responseElement is:\n{}", convertToString(responseElement));

    Response response;
    logger.debug("Unmarshalling...");

    UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshaller(responseElement);
    response = (Response) unmarshaller.unmarshall(responseElement);

    logger.debug("Successfully unmarshalled");
```

I use Response to validate. It doesn't work.
How can I validate it?